# How to solve the following simultaneous equations?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, systems-of-equations

It doesn't look like it can be solved by the normal substitution method:

[image]

It is given in a paper and the solution is given as $m \geq 2 + \sqrt(3)$.

Comment: First of all, these are inequalities, not equations. Moreover, they don't look like "simultaneous" inequalities, but rather as two cases that depend on whether $\theta_{12}$ is less or greater than a threshold value of $\frac{m-1}{m}\pi$. Without knowing more about the context, it's hard to say anything else.

Comment: @zipirovich I plugged it into Wolfram Alpha and it is able to give me solutions? Which means it is solvable without more context? I doubt you will want to read the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08063.pdf. It is at section 3.4.

Comment: Why not? Out of curiosity, I checked it out -- it's an interesting read. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, it looks like two inequalities for two possible cases depending on some threshold value. Let's look at them one at a time. Before we start, some observations from the original paper: $\theta_{12}$ is a positive angle; the parameter $m$ satisfies $m\ge2$; and they cautiously say that "we could have $m_{\text{min}}\ge2+\sqrt{3}$" (note "could" rather than "is").

**Case 1.** Note that $\theta_{12}$ is a common factor in all terms of the inequality. Since it's a positive number, we can divide both sides of the inequality by $\theta_{12}$:
$$\frac{1}{m-1}+\frac{1}{m+1}\le\frac{m-1}{m+1}.$$
Since $m\ge2$, we know that $m-1>0$ and $m+1>0$, so we can multiply both sides by $(m-1)(m+1)$:
$$(m+1)+(m-1)\le(m-1)^2.$$
Rearranging the terms and simplifying, we end up with a pretty standard quadratic inequality
$$m^2-4m+1\ge0,$$
whose solutions is
$$m\in(-\infty,2-\sqrt{3}]\cup[2+\sqrt{3},+\infty).$$
Since $m\ge2$ and they are looking for a minimal value of $m$, that's why from this answer it's reasonable (in the context) to say that "we could have $m_{\text{min}}\ge2+\sqrt{3}$".

**Case 2.** Note that $m+1$ is the same denominator in all terms of the inequality. Since it's a positive number, we can multiply both sides of the inequality by $m+1$ to obtain:
$$(2\pi-\theta_{12})+\theta_{12}\le(m-1)\theta_{12},$$
which simplifies, using the fact that $m-1$ is positive, to:
$$\theta_{12}\ge\frac{2\pi}{m-1}. \tag{1}\label{sol}$$
This case is a little trickier. Remember that we're considering the case when
$$\theta_{12}>\frac{m-1}{m}\pi. \tag{2}\label{con}$$

To make sure that a value of $\theta_{12}$ that satisfies the constraint \eqref{con} will satisfy the desired inequality \eqref{sol}, we should require that
$$\frac{m-1}{m}\pi\ge\frac{2\pi}{m-1}.$$
We can divide both sides by the common factor of $\pi$. Rearranging and simplifying further, we (interestingly enough!) end up with the same quadratic inequality
$$m^2-4m+1\ge0,$$
thus obtaining the same solution for this case too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. Do you know why there are these two cases? Especially with respect to the condition at the end that $\theta_{12} > \frac{m-1}{m}\pi$ and $\theta_{12} \geq \frac{m-1}{m}\pi$. I tried drawing out graphically the possible cases and they do give me the two equations but I cannot relate to the conditions.

Comment: @user136266: To be honest -- no, I don't know. I couldn't find in the paper any calculations leading to these two cases. Sorry...

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!